# Property attribute on single line?

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I got the following code:

```
[Column]
public int Id;
```

When I remove and readd a bracket, VS 2013 changes this to :

```
[Column] public int Id;
```

I don't want this. It is a fresh installation with ReSharper Added. I am unsure where to change the setting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to <kbd>RESHARPER</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Code-Editing</kbd> -> <kbd>C#</kbd> -> <kbd>Formatting Style</kbd> -> <kbd>Line Breaks and Wrapping</kbd> -> <kbd>Other</kbd>

and deselect

*Place singleline accessor attribute on same line*
*Place multiline accessor attribute on same line*

Comment: Surprisingly even though the preview in Resharper shows that these are the right settings it still had no effect. Is there a similar VS-Setting anywhere, perhaps?

Comment: Update: It was "place Singleline accessor attribute on same line" also

Comment: It's nolonger placed under "Other" in "Line Breaks and Wrapping" > "Arrangement of attributes"